# The Web Application Project "Project name" is configured to iis.The Web server 'http://dnndev.me/desktopmodules/"project name" could not be found

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2013, dotnetnuke

The Web Application Project "Project name" is configured to iis.The Web server 'http://dnndev.me/desktopmodules/"project name" could not be found.

I am using dotnetnuke 8 and i configured it with iis.I want to project it from visual studio 2013 ultimate update 4.

Comment: Are you using DNN Platform 8 (ctp), or are you using Evoq8?

Comment: And you have DNNDEV.ME setup as the URL for the site in IIS?

Comment: yes i added URL in iis....thanks sir...i got solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically occurs when you don't have the BINDING in IIS for DNNDEV.ME. It looks like from the comments that solved your problem.